# Can't deploy properly

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

Trying to deploy a simple Spring MVC webapp to localhost tomcat server.
At first I'd like to figure out how to set those.

> WARNING:   No rules found matching 'Host/WatchedResource'.
>   WARNING:   No rules found matching 'Host'.

In my maven-war-plugin I have

```
<webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
```

With this path I can successfully build my war file.
In tomcat-plugin I have

```
<contextFile>src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml< /contextFile>
```

My folder hierarchy:

```
+ src  
--- main  
--- java  
------myJavaFiles  
--- webapp  
------META-INF  
------------context.xml  
------WEB-INF  
---------resources  
------------application.properties  
------------applicationContext.xml  
------------dispatcher-servlet.xml  
---------web.xml  
------index.jsp
```

my context.xml

```
<WatchedResource>/WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
```

my web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/resources/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>  
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>  
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myApp/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong ? Thank you in advance